# Getting first chance exception while querying work items from tfs

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to generate/run some report by querying work items from TFS using C#.

Referred [this](https://bilearnings.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/connect-to-tfs-server-and-get-workitems-related-to-projects-using-c-net/) link. This code worked fine couple of months back and was able to retrieve the results.

Not sure why am getting below exception at Line 2

```
var tfsUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TfsCollection");
var uri = new Uri(tfsUrl);
var projCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
                            .GetTeamProjectCollection(uri);

//var workItemStore = projCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>(); //Line 1

var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(projCollection);  //Line 2
```

Tried other ways of querying work items like Line 1, but no luck. Any help here would be highly appreciated. Also, is there any better way of querying TFS using C#?

**Exception details**:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

```
System.ArgumentNullException occurred
_HResult=-2147467261
_message=Value cannot be null.    
HResult=-2147467261
IsTransient=false
Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=value
  StackTrace:
       at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Enabled this option in VS.

[Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDGqV.png)

Code will execute despite of the exception.

Comment: Thanks fro the sharing .You could mark it as answered.